# Can you run an exe file made with linux on windows

Tags: linux, windows, c

I compiled a c file on my linux machine and named it test.exe, is it possible to run that file on windows?

Comment: You would need to test it. If it is bland standard C with no special OS functions, it should work. But you need to try it and fix any shortcomings.

Comment: "I compiled a c file on my Linux machine and named it test.exe, is it possible to run that file on windows?" - It is absolutely possible to compile a Windows executable on Linux. `Can your literal executable be run on Windows?`...You have not provided enough information to answer that question.  You should [edit] your question to provide the necessary information.  All you would have to do is use a compiler that exists on both Linux and Windows, and use the appropriate flags, to indicate what you want is a Windows executable.

Comment: Not with what you probably did, but there's the mingw toolchain, i.e. you'll need to "cross-compile" it specifically for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I compiled a c file on my linux machine and named it test.exe, is it possible to run that file on windows?

The answer is simple: no, for at least two reasons.
(This answer assumes that the Windows Subsystem for Linux is not involved.)

1. An executable file in Linux typically uses the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), the Executable_and_Linkable_Format.  There's also the older [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF).
   Whereas Windows uses or has used [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file#DOS_binary_format), [DOS MZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable), [NE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable), [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), and [PE32+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).
   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats

The typical compiled and linked executable is not a standalone binary image that can be loaded (i.e. copied into memory from a storage device) and then simply executed.
Instead the executable is typically organized into sections for code, data, symbol information, and library requirements.
The layout of this information must be recognizable by the linker/loader utility of the OS, which is responsible for startup of user programs.

Renaming the execute file is not going to change the format of that file to make it compatible with another OS.

2. The C libraries of Linux and Windows are incompatible.
   C is a higher-level language that is portable only at the source code level.
   Once that source code is compiled, the object code becomes dependent on the processor architecture that the compiler is targeted for, and the C library the code is compiled for.

Many capabilities of the C language are implemented as functions and procedures in a companion C library.  Substring, math, and input/output routines are all in this C library that a C program may use.
Yes, a C program can be written to avoid invoking use of almost every C library routine.  But there is a key routine that initializes the C runtime environment that is compatible with the host OS.  This C runtime environment includes the stack, heap, and variable/data initialization.

Since a C program depends on a companion C library (that itself is OS & CPU architecture dependent), that C program once compiled inherits those same dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up a few C examples that said they were compiled in Linux. I looked for examples that had no special Linux functions or hooks.

If that is the case and the source code is bland, standard C,then it should work because C is reasonably portable.

You would need to try it and see if it works, and recompile in Windows if need be.

Here are methods of portable C code to be run across different environments that you may find helpful.

> When a program uses only defined behaviour (no undefined, unspecified
> or implementation defined behaviours), then the program is guarenteed
> by the lanugage standard (in your case C language standard) to compile
> (using a standards compliant compiler) and run uniformly on all
> operating systems.
>
> Basically you've to understand that a language standard like C or a
> library standard like OpenGL gives a set of minimum assumable
> guarentees that a programmer can make and build upon. These won't
> change as long as the compiler is compliant with the standard (in case
> of a library, the implementation is standards-compilant) and the
> program is not treading in undefined behaviour

[Portable C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310044/how-a-program-become-independent-of-os)